# Display first folder name in path

Tags: c#

Hi is there a way to extract the first dir name from the path then display to textbox. like C:\1stFolder\2nFolder\3rdFolder, then i want to display 1stFolder in the textbox

i have a code that only display current selected folder.

```
textBox5.Text = new DirectoryInfo(FBD.SelectedPath).Name;
```

Comment: Look at the `System.IO.Path` class for constructing and deconstructing file and folder paths. Be aware that, in your case, it might take multiple method calls to extract the specific part you want, but that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\1stFolder\2nFolder\3rdFolder");
while(di.Parent != null && di.Parent.Parent != null)
{
    di = di.Parent;
}
string firstFolderName = di.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

** Updated answer based on comment below **

Try this:

```
void Main()
{
    var dir = @"C:\1stFolder\2nFolder\3rdFolder";
    
    DirectoryInfo info = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dir);
    var root = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(dir);

    while (root != info.Parent.FullName)
    {
        info = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(info.FullName);
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(info.FullName);
}
```

Comment: he want get "1stFolder" not is "C:"

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something simple

```
using System.Linq;
var path = "c:\path\to\something";
var firstDirectory = path.Split("\\").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

or even

```
var firstDirectory = path.Split("\\")[1];
```